# ProgressRing not showing in Flyout

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

A simple button with a flyout that contains a ProgressRing.

```cs
<Button Name="cmdStart" Content="Start" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,5,0">
    <Button.Flyout>
        <Flyout Placement="Top">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <ProgressRing IsActive="True" Width="30" Height="30"/>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Username" FontSize="16" Width="90" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <PasswordBox Name="txtUsername" Width="100" Margin="10,5,5,5"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Password" FontSize="16" Width="90" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <PasswordBox Name="txtPassword" Width="100" Margin="10,5,5,5"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
                    <Button Name="cmdLoginProceed" Content="Login" Margin="5" Tapped="cmdLoginProceed_Tapped"/>
                    <Button Name="cmdLoginCancel" Content="Cancel" Margin="5" Tapped="cmdLoginCancel_Tapped"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </Flyout>
    </Button.Flyout>
</Button>
```

Tap on the button, the flyout pops up. No ProgressRing. Close the flyout and tap on the button again, flyout pops up and there it is!

If the flyout is replaced by a Grid or StackPanel (sets as Collapsed) and changed to Visible when tap on the button in button's code, ProgressRing shows as expected.

What have I done wrong?

*The ProgressRing in code serves no meaning yet, just to highlight the issue*

**Edit**: Is it possible issues with my installed tool & library version.

My setup:

> Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL
>
> Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.6.00079
>
> Visual C# 2015 Microsoft Visual C# 2015
>
> Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows Apps   14.0.23121.00 D14OOB

Comment: Maybe this can help http://bin.leet.af/?5dd054f3662266f1#OKuN6RtXUe+gX87rPHPcQteAuTLfdPqf7sPdGsI2u20=
example from MSDN, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.progressring

Comment: Tested the code that you pasted. Works fine. Take the same code and put inside the flyout (in my sample code), the toggle did not show the ProgressRing. But when show the flyout again, the toggle show the ProgressRing. Same problem, first time open flyout, ProgressRing not shown, only when opens second time.

Comment: Maybe you should try to change the placement to full and test if it shows up the first time

Comment: try to add some margin the progressring too ..

Comment: No visible effect. Anyone can replicate this behaviour?